# storing a string to a 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to store a sentence to a 2d array by separating each words. In the 2d array each row will contain each word from the sentence. Here is what I think I should do.

```
//Logic 
//given string mystring
string mystring = "testing the arrays";

//create a 2d char array to hold 4 words with 10 max size
char 2darr[4][10] = {" "};
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0,j=0; i <mystring.length(); i++)
{
    if (mystring(i) != ' ')
        2darr[x][j++] = mystring(i);  //copy the each character to the first row
    else
        2darr[x][j++] = '\0';
        ++x; // goes to next row
        j = 0; //reset j for new row
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I think my logic is a little off as well

Comment: What is `string`? What does its function-call operator do?

Comment: In C++ indentation is not significant, you need braces `{}` for scoping or to group multiple statements.

Comment: Why don't you use a vector of strings (`std::vector<std::string>`)?

Comment: *Is there a better way to do this?* -- The answer is "yes", and it doesn't involve any of this stuff with 2d char arrays.  The issue is that once such an answer is posted, you may say "but we can't use <fill_in_the_blank>" or "we haven't learned <fill_in_the_blank>".  So will a real C++ solution help you?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was asking if there was a better to store it on 2d array. I specifically want to store it on 2d array as I am learning 2d array for now. I wasn't asking for solution without 2d array.

Comment: I posted a solution that uses `stringstream` to parse, and `strncpy` to do the copy.  That eliminates all of that code you have that manually copies character-by-character, and also removes the need to check for spaces.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this is:

1) There is no need to check spaces.  For this to occur, you can use `std::istringstream` with `operator >>` to obtain each word in a loop.

2) Use `strncpy` to copy the string into the 2 dimensional array

3) You need to make sure that the string does not exceed the bounds of the array, and that you have no more than 4 separate words.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char arr2d[4][10] = {};
    std::string mystring = "testing the arrays";

    // create an input stream containing the test string
    std::istringstream strm(mystring);
    std::string word;

    // this is the word count 
    int curCount = 0;

    // obtain each word and copy to the array
    while (strm >> word && curCount < 4)
        strncpy(arr2d[curCount++], word.c_str(), 9);

    // output the results 
    for (int i = 0;  i < curCount; ++i)
      std::cout << arr2d[i] << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
testing
the
arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

1. this expression `char 2darr[4][10] = {" "}` will only set the first element to be `" "`, the others will be `'\0'` or `NULL`. But it is probably OK, since it is the default terminator of C-strings.
2. Variables can't start with a digit, call it arr2d instead.
3. String character access is `mystring[i]`, not `mystring(i)`
4. You only **indented** the lines in the `else` block, in C++ if you don't enclose a block with curly braces, it only captures the first row, what you basically wrote is:

```cpp
    else {
        2darr[x][j++] = '\0';
    }
    ++x; // goes to next row
    j = 0; //reset j for new row
```

Corrected code is

```cpp
    std::string mystring = "testing the arrays";

    //create a 2d char array to hold 4 words with 10 max size
    char arr2d[4][10] = { };
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mystring.length(); i++)
    {
        if (mystring[i] != ' ') {
            arr2d[x][j++] = mystring[i];  //copy the each character to the first row
        }
        else {
            arr2d[x][j++] = '\0';
            ++x; // goes to next row
            j = 0; //reset j for new row
        }
    }
```